# Robolectric can find parent style

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, robolectric

When a run my tests with Robolectric, I got this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: huh? can't find parent for StyleData{name='AppTheme', parent='Theme_AppCompat_Light_DarkActionBar'}
....
```

What is the problem?

thank you

Comment: My wild guess is Robolectric doesn't see AndroidManifest.xml. Do you see any warning in console when robolectric starts?